# Add more consumers later after AddMassTransit has already been called somewhere else (using ms dependency injection)

Tags: masstransit

A module adds the MassTransit to the DI and after it is done (where IServiceCollection.AddMassTransit(...) part already finished, some other module wants to add further  consumers to the bus.
How can I do that?

//Module 1

//...

services.AddMassTransit(x =>

{

//....

x.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();

x.AddConsumer ConsumerOfModule1

//....

}

//Module 2

//...

// HOW TO: x.AddConsumer ConsumerOfModule2

//....

Comment: Simple answer, you can't.

Comment: Too bad :-(
As a last resort, I pass an Action<IServiceCollectionBusConfigurator> callback to module1
Inside AddMassTransit action, I invoke it giving a chance to module2 to add its consumer.
But this is kind of against the dependency injection sprit, isn't it?

Comment: Not really, it's part of container setup.